# Async Function Call in Recursion using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to call Async function in recursion actually I have Async method - async function `getSSN(req,res,next)` and inside this function block I need to call this function but when I call this method by code - `return await getSSN(req,res,next)` this code is not working for me in node js. Can anyone give me solution for that.?

Comment: Could you provide the code you already tried? It is hard to say what is the issue without looking at the code

Comment: Please show the larger code context.  A question like this can't be answered generically.  You need to show your actual code in context for us to know how to answer or what to recommend.  FYI, questions here about code should always show the relevant code.  Not just one line of code, but the whole context for the code.  Also, it doesn't really make sense in the abstract to be passing `(req, res, next)` to  something recursively because you can't call `next()` or send a response more than once.  So, probably, there's a better way to solve whatever you're trying to solve.

Comment: async function getSSN(next)
{
  request.get('https://idms.dealersocket.com/api/account/getaccountlist?token='+dealertoken+'&LayoutID=2002313&PageNumber='+count+'&accounttype=i&accountstatus=a,c,b,o,r,s,x',
  (err,res) => {
    if(count<=totalpage){
    console.log(res);
    let result = JSON.parse(res.body);
    let data = Object.assign({},result.Data);
    let len = Object.keys(data).length;
    for(var i=0;i<=len;i++){
    ssn.push(data[i].Row.Borrower1SSN);
    }
    count++;
    }
  })
}
This is my code @jfriend00

Comment: I need to call getSSN() after count++ variable and I have tried following statements:
return await getSSN()
return await getSSN(req,res,next)
return await Promise.all([getSSN()]) @ErangaHeshan

Comment: @mehuldaxini - Please use the "edit" link below your question to add the code context to your question itself and format it appropriately as code.  Multi-line code snippets are not readable in comments and your question itself needs to stand on its own with this code in it.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't mix `async/await` with plain asynchronous callbacks.  They do not work properly.  Your `async` function `getSSN()` is not properly resolving when your `request.get()` finishes because that's just a plain asynchronous callback which the async function knows nothing about.

Instead, you need to use a promise-based `request()` option.  Since, the request library is now deprecated and should not be used for new projects, I would suggest [one of the alternatives](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) that are all based on promises already.  My favorite is the [`got()` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can look at the list of alternatives and pick the one that has a programming style you like.

In addition, your `getSSN()` function has a bunch of side effects (modifying higher scoped variables).  This is not a good way to program, particularly for asynchronous operations because the outside world generally doesn't know when things are done and when the higher scoped variables have the values in them you want them to.  You should make `getSSN()` return a promise that resolves to its result and then have the caller use that result to modify the higher scoped variables.  Again, if you showed us the rest of the coding context here, we could suggest a better overall way to do this.  Please notice here that you're just not providing enough code for us to be able to show you the best way to write this code.  That should be a general lesson for stackoverflow.  Err on the side of giving us more than you think and we can then often make suggestions and improvements far beyond what you even know to ask about.

Here's your function with all the ill-adivsed side effects still in it (because you haven't shown us the rest of the code) using `got()`:

```
async function getSSN(next) {
    const result = await got('idms.dealersocket.com/api/account/…').json();
    if (count <= totalpage) {
        const data = Object.assign({}, result.Data);
        const len = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
            ssn.push(data[i].Row.Borrower1SSN);
        }
        count++;
    }    
}
```

Now, `getSSN()` will return a promise that resolves or rejects when the network request is finished.